# update line row in telerik mvc grid

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have a grid like  this:

[image: common grid]

To edit a line, the user chooses one from the grid an click the "pen" icon. Then, the record is displayed in the form.

To save the form, choose the save button link. Ok.
Now I need to update the line in the grid. 
I get this working, doing the follow in javascript:

```
$.post(this.href,
        sf,
        function (response) {
            $("#form-edicao").html(response);
            var $grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
            $grid.rebind();  //==this line update the grid
        });
```

But this approach updates all the grid, return to the first page... 
I need to update just one line.
In common table grids, I replace some html elements. How to do this in this mysterious grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html) of the Grid component I think that using .ajaxRequest() instead might be what you're looking for. .rebind() resets the state (page number, filter/sort expressions etc.) while .ajaxRequest() shouldn't.